# Custom FriendlyUrls IN ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, routes, friendly-url

I am using routing(**Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls**) in ASP.NET Web forms.
When I have implement this and try to open **ProductDetail.aspx** it redirect me on the routing **ProductDetail**, but I want It redirect me on the already defined pattern like **product-detail** instead of **ProductDetail**.

Can any one help me in to this via **Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls**

Comment: Is this what you want to do: `string friendlyUrl = FriendlyUrl.Resolve("~/ProductDetail.aspx");` & `string link = FriendlyUrl.Href("~/product-detail", [URL parameters]);`? Explain more details how you want to implement `FriendlyUrls` with existing route(s).

Comment: now when I have hit the Page Url **ProductDetail.aspx** It redirect me on **ProductDetail** but I want It redirect me on some defined pattern like **product-detail"